# Алгоритм попадания точки в кривую

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть класс для отрисовки кривой:

```
class Curve
{
    // Набор точек.
    public List<Point> Points {get; set;}

    // Толщина кривой.
    public int Thinkness {get; set;}

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, Thinkness))
        {
            g.DrawCurve(pen, Points);
        }
    }
}
```

Отрисовка выполняется методом [Graphics.DrawCurve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ak09y3z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Нужно добавить метод, который будет определять, принадлежит ли произвольная точка этой кривой:

```
public bool Contains(Point pt);
```

Кто-нибудь может подсказать алгоритм, с помощью которого можно решить данную задачу? Может быть, каким-то образом можно использовать [Matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) или сам [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: Кубический сплайн можно аппроксимировать коротенькими отрезками, для отрезка задача решается просто, даже без тригонометрии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Придумал следующее решение.
В методе Draw рисуем не закругление (DrawCurve), а Path ([DrawPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx)). Способ получения Path и пера выносим в отдельные методы. После этого используем метод IsOutlineVisible для получения информации о вхождении точки в Path.

```
class Curve
{
    // Набор точек.
    public List<Point> Points {get; set;}

    // Толщина кривой.
    public int Thinkness {get; set;}

    private GraphicsPath GetPath()
    {
        var path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddCurve(Points.ToArray());
        return path;
    }

    private Pen GetPen()
    {
        return new Pen(Color.Black, Thinkness);
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        using (var pen = GetPen())
        using (var path = GetPath())
        {
            g.DrawPath(pen, path);
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(Point p)
    {
        using (var pen = GetPen())
        using (var path = GetPath())
        {
            return path.IsOutlineVisible(p, pen);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DrawCurve` использует [кубический сплайн](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), который задается параметрически как полином третьей степени с векторами в качестве коэффициентов. Если есть опыт решения кубических уравнений - можно попробовать сначала восстановить формулу, а потом проверять точку по получившейся системе из двух кубических уравнений.

Если желания лезть в математику нет - то проще всего нарисовать где-нибудь эту линию, после чего просто проверять цвет пикселя.

Comment: Была идея проверять цвет, но это не вариант из-за накладных расходов. Особого желания углубляться в математику тоже нет, но, видимо, придется. Благодарю за наводку.

Answer (score 0):

Нам нужны по идее две вещи: проекция точки на прямую и расстояние от точки до прямой.

```
class Line
{
    Point start;
    UnitVector direction;
}

Point projectCoord(Point x, Line l)
{
    return Tools.DotProduct(x - line.start, line.direction);
}

Point projection(Point x, Line l)
{
    return line.Start + line.Direction * projectCoord(x, line);
}

double signedDistance(Point p, line l)
{
    if (p == line.Start) return null;
    return Tools.CrossProduct(p - line.Start, line.direction);
}
```

Имея эти методы, всё по идее просто:

```
class Segment
{
    Line Line;
    double StartCoord, EndCoord;
}

bool belongs(Point p, Segment s, double width)
{
    return 
        IsBetween(projectCoord(p, s.Line), s.StartCoord, s.EndCoord)) &&
        Math.Abs(signedDistance(p, s.Line)) < width;
}
```

Вспомогательные функции:

```
// скалярное произведение
double DotProduct(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
}

// векторное произведение
double CrossProduct(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x;
}
```

Ну и точка попадает в ломаную линию, если она попадает хотя бы в одну из её частей.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Был кривой заголовок в вопросе. Ваш ответ относится именно к ломанной линии. Меня интересует способ получить такой результат для кривой, нарисованной с использованием метода DrawCurve.